# How to move objects in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have Realm data model

```
import RealmSwift

class Priority: Object {

    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var text = ""
    dynamic var time = ""
}
```

And I can get all the stored objects

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let objects = realm.objects(Priority)
```

How to move an object from the index 7 in the index 3 and save the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects stored in a Realm are unordered. If you want to store an ordered list of objects you can do so using a `List<T>` property on a model class. [`List` provides mutation methods](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html#/Mutation) that can be used to change the order of objects within the list.

Comment: I have to create an additional model which will " let list = List<Priority>() " and only work with this model?

Comment: Yes, the you can play with the list ordering of items, Object is managed by Realm. You can always access Objects, but you can work with List

Answer (score 3):

You can put the Objects in `Realm List`, then you can use both `move` and `swap` methods to reorder.

Here is the `List` API: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html